# Build failed with an exception. Flutter Framework

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/delegate_widget.dart:194:18: Error: Superclass has no method named 'inheritFromElement'.
    return super.inheritFromElement(ancestor, aspect: aspect);
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:259:19: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
        ? context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type) as InheritedProvider<T>
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:260:19: Error: The method 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType'.
        : context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                                        

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: [What is your answerable programming question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)